# Get Tumblr Tokens without having to go to a website?

Tags: python, api, rest, tumblr

I'm using **PyTumblr**. I have the **Consumer Key** & **Consumer Secret** and I'm trying to requests the **Access token** and the **Token Secret**

In the pytumblr github page they say:

> Two easy ways to get your credentials to are:
>
> 1. The built-in interactive_console.py tool (if you already have a
>      consumer key & secret)
> 2. The Tumblr API console at https://api.tumblr.com/console

Oh nice, but the `interactive_console.py` waits for user interaction. Basically It sends you to a web page to autorize the Tumblr APP you want to access.

As you can see here:
https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/blob/master/interactive_console.py

They say:

```
# Redirect to authentication page
print '\nPlease go here and authorize:\n%s?oauth_token=%s' % (authorize_url, request_token['oauth_token'][0])
redirect_response = raw_input('Allow then paste the full redirect URL here:\n')
```

And the second way directly is to access a website.

My question is: **Is there any way to get the tokens without interacting with a website (just programmatically) to autorize it, then get the tokens ?**

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Tumblr uses oauth, which requires the creation of per-session keys to interact with the service.

Comment: Then, and just to confirm...  You're saying that is a MUST to autorize It through a web page ? :( And It's not a Tumblr behaviour, just the way oauth works ?